# IAR fails to compile mutex library for ARM AM3357, Fatal Error Pe035

Tags: arm, mutex, microcontroller, ethereum, iar

I'm trying to implement the `EtHash` algorithm in the AM3357 microcontroller, but when I try to include the mutex library it shows the following error:

> Fatal Error [Pe035]: #error directive: "IAR Systems does not support mutex"

I've already tried to enable parallel build,  put the full path of mutex library and multicore debugging, nothing worked

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: Is the code trying to make use of the mutex found in the standard C threading library, or some other form of mutex?

Comment: I'm using the mutex library from c++ (#include <mutex>)

Answer (score 0):

Iccarm has no support for the concurrency parts of the standard C++ library. You need to choose a specific RTOS and use the concurrency primitives provided by this operating system when implementing your algorithm.